# Open received email via ms-outlook://emails/ URI Scheme

Tags: android, outlook, deep-linking

I see it's possible to automatically compose new emails on Android using the

```
ms-outlook://emails/new?to=example@mail.com&subject=subject&body=body
```

URI scheme, I was wondering if there would be a way to open the outlook application to a specific existing email, using this URI scheme, if I had the message ID of the email I want to open to.

e.g. something like `ms-outlook://emails/view?id=ABC123`

I couldn't find any documentation for the ms-outlook URI scheme online.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ms-outlook://emails/message/<id>
```

Comment: is there any documentation for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I just decompiled outlook.apk  and found this string.

`StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("ms-outlook://emails/message/");
            AcronymAnswerSearchResult.AcronymAnswerSearchItem.EmailSource emailSource = acronymAnswerSearchItem.getEmailSource();
            Intrinsics.m19680d(emailSource);
            sb.append(Uri.encode(emailSource.getId()));
            sb.append("?account=");
            sb.append(acronymAnswerSearchItem.getAccountId());`

Comment: There is also mention about **accountID**, but it will be hard to get ...

Comment: can you please try to decompile the Microsoft To Do APK? If an email is flagged and there's a task for it in To Do Flagged Emails, there's a button to open the email in Outlook. I think To Do holds the answer how you can open an Email by id in Outlook...